# Count Function for identifying the Unique values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Here I need to identify the overall count by Ignoring the duplicate values in both rows.

Example:

[image]

Here I need to compare if AAAA value whether presented in the top row and in the same row (other cells). In this case the overall count is 7 after ignoring the duplicates count.

I tried with this function `=Countif(F10,"<>"&L8) +Countif(H10,"<>"&L8)..,` --> this expression only compares for single condition, but I need to compare both rows. Referencing the Value row 10 for each cells and Row 8.

Answer (score 0):

If 9th row is empty:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TOCOL(F8:R10)))-1
```

If not:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(TOCOL(VSTACK(F8:R8,F10:R10))))-1
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: TOCOL is for Beta version.. Thats why I'm getting 0 as Output

I couldn't able to attach the image

Comment: If formula is not available I think it would make #NAME? error instead of giving incorrect result. Could you update your post with screenshot? What Excel version do you use?

Comment: I identified the solution for this case, thanks. but TOCOL is not working